# Проверить есть ли текущая строка в списке Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, if, for

Есть цикл который перебирает строки, строки могут повторятся, если строка повторяется то нужно присвоить последовательный номер. Если не повторяется то начать присваивание номера заного каждому повторяющемиуся элементу. Вместо этого у меня присваевается номер последовательно каждой новой строки несмотря на то что они разные.
Подскажите что не так?

objects:

```
A0001
A0001
A0002
A0002
A0002
A0002
A0002
A0004
A0004
A0006
A0006
A0006
```

Script:

```
art_sort_no = []
sort_no = 0
for obj in objects:
    art_no = obj.get('art_no').strip()
    if art_no in art_sort_no:
        art_sort_no.append(art_no)
        sort_no += 1
        print(art_no, sort_no)
    else:
        art_sort_no.clear()
        art_sort_no.append(art_no)
        print(art_no, sort_no)
```

Я хочу видеть что то вроде этого:

```
A0001 1
A0001 2
A0002 1
A0002 2
A0002 3
A0002 4
A0002 5
A0004 1 
A0004 2
A0006 1
A0006 2
A0006 3
```

Но получается во так:

```
A0001 1
A0001 2
A0002 3
A0002 4
A0002 5
A0002 6
A0002 7
A0004 8 
A0004 9
A0006 10
A0006 11
A0006 12
```

Comment: `else: sort_no=1`

Comment: ну так ты sort_no только увеличиваешь, но нигде не сбрасываешь на начальное значение

Answer (score 0):

Для решения этой задачи нужно воспользоваться частотным словарём
Вот пример может не самый идеальный, но точно рабочий:

```py
text = """A0001
A0001
A0002
A0002
A0002
A0002
A0002
A0004
A0004
A0006
A0006
A0006"""

text = text.split()

res_dict = dict()
result = ''

for i in text:
    if i in res_dict:
        res_dict[i] += 1
        result += f'{i} {res_dict[i]} \n'
    else:
        res_dict[i] = 1
        result += f'{i} {res_dict[i]} \n'
```

Результат:

```
A0001 1 
A0001 2
A0002 1
A0002 2
A0002 3
A0002 4
A0002 5
A0004 1
A0004 2
A0006 1
A0006 2
A0006 3
```